# Updating recordset in VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, sql-update, recordset

Quick question, new to this site, new to programming especially.

I'm trying to Select data from SqlServer and then update it while it's still a recordset. I don't want to update the actual table with the data....
So if I have a field called RS!("FirstName") and I want to add a string to it, for example "MR"

This is how I go about it

```
str = "Select FirstName from tblClient"
rs.Open SQL, g_cn, adOpenStatic

rs.movefirst
do while not rs.eof 
    rs("FirstName") = "MR" & rs("FirstName") <--- this is what i'm trying to do but it tells me I cannot update it. 
    rs.movenext
loop
```

How to fix this

Comment: is it this hard? am i doing the wrong thing? is it impossible? damn at least a comment or something

Comment: It has been years since I have done VB6, but I looked at some of our old code and it has stuff like: `rs![FirstName] = "MR " & rs![FirstName]`.

Comment: @mark i think it has something to do with the cursor, I've tried adopendynamic and all that stuff but the error just says current recordset does not allow updating

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx), lock type defaults to `adLockReadOnly`, so you probably need to specify `adLockOptimistic` or something else that allows updates - `rs.Open SQL, g_cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic`.

Comment: @mark The thing is I don't want to update the table, i want to update the data in recordset before loading it to combobox

Comment: i've trying every cursor and lock type keeps givng me the same error. Frustrating!!

Comment: Have you checked the answers below - update your code in your question. If you're using what you're currently showing it's not going to work. Change the `rs.Open` line like I said in my answer - and then update your question with your current code and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show all your code to make it easier to help you.

From what you DO show - an obvious fix is to use your str variable.
It would show up quicker if you add an Option Explicit at the very top of your module, then you could tell you havn't declared some of your vars

In any case if you use the sql you declared - and - change your recordset type it should work

Change:

```
str = "Select FirstName from tblClient"
rs.Open SQL, g_cn, adOpenStatic
```

To:

```
str = "Select FirstName from tblClient"
rs.Open str, g_cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

Loop:

```
rs.Edit
rs("FirstName") = "MR" & rs("FirstName") 
rs.Update
rs.movenext
```

Comment: str is declared as String. With the rs.open that you changed it to does not work, it goes right to error handler giving me error 3001 - arguments are of the wrong type, out of range. If i take one of the commas out, that's when it works, but it doesn't let me update

Comment: Remove extra comma - use `rs.Open str, g_cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic` - add  Edit before and Update after

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is to create a new disconnected recordset. You can do to it what you want and just set it to nothing when you're finished. You can do it specifically to the recordset you want to modify or write a more generic method that copies the source recordset.

Here is a generic example. rsOriginal is the recordset passed in and used in code later. rsUpdateable is a local recordset built as a copy of the original, then assigned to the original recordset variable. It is now completely updateable and changes cannot be saved back to the source table.

```
...

'clone a recordset into a new updateable recordset
Dim rsUpdateable As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
'errors here are unlikely, but if  happens I don't want to alert the user
On Error Resume Next
'build the table schema
For Each fld In rsOriginal.Fields
    rsUpdateable.Fields.Append fld.Name, fld.Type, fld.DefinedSize
Next fld
rsUpdateable.Open
'populate the new recordset with the original values
rsUpdateable.AddNew
For Each fld In rsOriginal.Fields
    rsUpdateable.Fields(fld.Name).Value = fld.Value
Next fld
Set rs = rsUpdateable   'done
On Error GoTo OriginalErrorHandler    'restore error handler

...
```

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new recordset - I would like to update the data in my recordset before it gets loaded into a combobox. So basically if my recorset consists of values like : Mike, John, Bob, Jane (each of these values has an ID) - and then based on the ID (in which case I'd do a case statement) I want to added "MR" in front of each male (based on ID) so it would look like : MR. Mike, Mr. John, Mr. Bob and then use these values to load my combobox.

Comment: @user6539508 I developed this because I was in a similar situation where I needed to update data in the original recordset that would never be saved back to the database. This was the easy method I used to get around the original recordset not being updateable.